# Aggregate array values for some keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm facing a great question in how to manage my array.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Rule [1] => 0,5 [2] => Name [3] => Task ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Another rule [1] => 2 [2] => name [3] => Task ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Rule [1] => 1 [2] => name [3] => Sub-Task ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Another rule [1] => 1 [2] => another name [3] => Sub-Task ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Rule [1] => 1 [2] => another name [3] => Task ) etc...
```

I need to aggregate (in another array) values for "name" and "task" just to have this view:

```
name -> task -> 10 -> rule
     -> task -> 5 -> another rule
     -> Sub Task -> 20 -> another rule
     -> Sub task -> 0 -> rule
another name -> task -> 10 -> rule
         -> task -> 5 -> another rule
         -> Sub Task -> 20 -> another rule
         -> Sub task -> 0 -> rule
```

It's a bit hard to do for me and I cannot figure out how to manage it.

I've tried array_map, several foreach with if condition inside, but nothing.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the desired output in array format? and also where do these numbers 10,20 come from?

Comment: Hello, it should be something like that:

[NAME] => Array (
    [Task] => 4 array ('rule' => rule)
    [Sub-Task] => 4 array ('rule' => rule)
    )
[ANOTHER NAME] => Array (
    [Task] => 2 array ('rule' => rule)
    )
[ONE MORE NAME] => Array (
    [Task] => 1,5 array ('rule' => rule)
    [Sub-Task] => 4 array ('rule' => rule)
    )

The "rule" array can be blank too, I don't need it if it's too hard to embed